# How to upload to other sub folder outside my webpage environment

Tags: php, file-upload

All my web pages including upload.php where the code that upload the image to the directory his, are all in the folder called pages(main >> pages) but i want to upload my image to the folder outside the page folder name img(main >> allimage >> img) help my fix this on my $img_path code below thanks.

```
    This is where i want the uploaded image should go: 
    (main >> allimage >> img)
    This is where the upload.php his:
    (main >> pages)

**upload.php**
    $img_path = './allimage/img/'.time().rand().'.'.end(explode('.',$_FILES['eimage']['name']));    
    copy($_FILES['eimage']['tmp_name'],$img_path);
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is completely unclear. You did change the path. So what is left?

Comment: I want to upload to this directory (main >> allimage >> img ) my upload.php page is in this directory(main >> pages) i this  $img_path = './allimage/img/'.time().rand().'.'.end(explode('.',$_FILES['eimage']['name'])); and am getting this error  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ....

Comment: You did say so before. But you still did not alter your question to make clear what you actually ask.

Comment: @arkascha user wants to upload to other sub folder

Comment: I'd say you have to create those folders first. A `copy` call does not autoamagically do that for you. Also I am pretty sure you want to use the `move_uploaded_file` function instead of `copy`....